# gWidgets add space between elements gcheckboxgroup

Tags: r, gwidgets

I'm trying to generate a checkboxgroup horizontal, and I will like to add spaces between elements because I want that the checkboxgroup and its frame fit the width of window.

```
alloptions<-gcheckboxgroup(c("BoxPlot", "Tree", "PCA"),
                       horizontal=TRUE, 
                       handler=function(h,...) {
                         option<<-svalue(alloptions)
                       })
fr1<-gframe("Procedures", container=group3)
add(fr1,alloptions)
```

Thank you

Comment: I have tried addSpace and spacing but they didn't work for checkboxgroup.

Comment: You need to use `expand=TRUE, fill="x"` when you call add. This depends on the container. For a horizontal box the above is needed. For a vertical box, the children expand to fill horizontally (in a horizontal box, the children expand to fill vertically).